# Crystal Reports PO add second page Terms & Conditions

Tags: crystal-reports

Our ERP system Macola has a PO form created with Crystal Reports. I need to add a second page, Terms & Conditions. I've tried several suggestion from the web with no luck. The second page prints with the Terms & Conditions, but the first page header information still prints. I tried the suppression using pagenumber >1, but when you look at the printout of the second page, the page number is 1 so this formula doesnt suppress the header information. Any help would be appreciated. Its amazing that just adding a second page with terms & conditions would be that difficult. Is there an easy way to add a PDF to the last page, not using subreport.

Answer (score 1):

I have a few reports that do exactly what you describe.  The way I designed the reports was to put the Terms & Conditions in the Report Footer section.  Then in the Section Expert for the Report Footer I checked the box for "New Page Before" on the Paging tab.  This ensures this section always begins on a new page.  As for suppressing the Page Header on the last page, I used the following formula.

```
PageNumber = TotalPageCount;
```

I also used this same formula in the Page Footer section to ensure it is suppressed on the last page as well.

This design also assumes that the user will never print more than a single PO at once.  If your users need to print a range of Purchase Orders at once, this design will only print the Terms & Conditions page once regardless of how may Purchase Orders are being printed.

Also, based on what you said about your `pagenumber > 1` formula not working as expected, you may want to go through each section in the Section Expert and inspect the Paging tab to see if any sections have "Reset Page Number After" enabled.  Any sections that have this enabled will force page numbers to reset back to 1 after that section prints and could cause any formula that evaluates PageNumber to behave unexpectedly.